# Is there a java script I can write to switch between the locale files I've created?

Tags: javascript, django, locale

so I have this select tag that get the languages from the setting but I don't know how to write if the user choose Spanish get the Spanish file to translate text

```html
<label>Language:</label>
<select name="language" id="id_language">
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
            <option>
                {{ lang.1 }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>

<h1>{% trans hello %}</h1>
<h2>{% trans 'This is a translation template' %}</h2>
```

Comment: Since Django is a backend framework, everything it does is pre-processing before the page is loaded or before the user sees anything. Any templating that you want to interact with the frontend and user is impossible. The only way to accomplish this is to send a request to your own server upon selection of a language, then implement an endpoint on the backend to handle the request and respond with the translation.

Comment: so I need to send the language code as a parameter to the views and translate from there?

Comment: Yes, are you familiar with AJAX requests?

Comment: Also if you want to make the display of the translation be on a separate page you can just create a form out of the select, submit it to another page which has a view handled by Django, and access the form data from there.

Comment: Yes, I just tried what you said and it worked perfectly. I don't want it in a separate page. I want it in the same page but when I select the value so I am using  document.getElementById("selectLanguage").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("languageForm").submit();
    };  but it's not working can you please help me with this?

Comment: If you want it on the same page without then submitting a form won't help you. You have to invoke an AJAX request on click instead.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help, let me know if you have any more trouble.